# Cannot load the "shell32.dll" DLL into memory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, impersonation

I have a problem with a program that i'm writing in VB.net. It is a program to start a third party service on a remote server. When i run the program it works just fine but i have administrator rights. The idea is that certain people can use this program when this certain service stops.

I used an impersonation to give the program administrator rights by using following code:

```
Public Sub ImpersonateStart(ByVal Domain As String, ByVal userName As 
String, ByVal Password As String)
    Try
        tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero
        ' Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
        Dim returnValue As Boolean = LogonUser(userName, Domain, Password, 
 2, 0, tokenHandle)
        'check if logon successful

        If returnValue = False Then
            Dim ret As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
            Console.WriteLine("LogonUser failed with error code : {0}", ret)
            Throw New System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret)
            Exit Sub

        End If
        'Logon succeeded
        ' Use the token handle returned by LogonUser.
        Dim newId As New WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle)
        impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate()
    Catch ex As Exception

        Throw ex
        Exit Sub
    End Try

End Sub
```

In my actual code i use 
imp.ImpersonateStart("DOMAIN", "administrator", "PASSWORD")

But when i run the program i get the folowing error:
[image]
What am i doing wrong?

Thnx